# Sending sms on multiple emulator at time

Tags: java, android

1. I'm developing an Android app where i need to send single message to
   receive multiple emulator at a time .But the problem is only one
   emulator is receiving the message.Here is my code.

   public class SMS extends Activity
   {

   ```
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SendSms);

       txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_PhoneNumber);

       txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_MessageBody);

       btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

       {
           public void onClick(View v) 

           {                
               String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

               String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();

               StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");

               while (st.hasMoreElements())

               {
                   String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();

                   if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && message.trim().length()>0)

                   {
                       sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, message);
                   }

                   else 

                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 

                               "Please enter both phone number and message.", 

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }

           }
       });  

   }


   private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)

   {
       String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

       String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

       PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

       PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

     //---when the SMS has been sent---
       registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()

       {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 

           {
               switch (getResultCode())


               {

                   case Activity.RESULT_OK:


                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;

                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:


                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       break;

                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;

                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;

                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 

                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
               }
           }
       } , new IntentFilter(SENT));



       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

       sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an SMS message to another emulator instance which running on same machine, launch the SMS application. Specify the console port number(ex:5555) of the target emulator instance as as the SMS address.

Please note that this answer is based on :[Linuxtopia](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/android_emulator_calling.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array of emulator id or number then put **sendTextMessage** into that execute the loop as many element into the the array. OR You can have UI that allow the user to insert the phone number or emulator number in to the list and same procedure as above !!! 
note that **sendTextMessage** `s **first** argument is **"Phone Number"** to whom you want to send sms
simply replace it with your requirement every as loop iterate